# Mysql - HASH PARITION vs RANGE PARTITION on a DATETIME column?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

Can someone tell me pros and cons of HASH PARITION vs RANGE PARTITION on a DATETIME column?
Let consider we have POS table with 20 milion records and would want to create partitions based on transaction date's year like

```
PARTITION BY HASH(YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE)) PARTITIONS 4;
```

or

```
PARTITION BY RANGE(YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE)) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2010),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2012),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2013),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

to improve performance of queries with TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2013-03-01' AND '2013-09-29'

Which one better over the other? and why?

Comment: I think you should ask this on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some significant differences.  If you have a `where` clause that refers to a range of years, such as:

```
where year(transaction_date) between 2009 and 2011
```

then I don't think the hash partitioning will recognize this as hitting just one, two, or three partitions.  The range partitioning should recognize this, reducing the I/O for such a query.

The more important difference has to do with managing the data.  With range partitioning, once a partition has been created -- and the year has past -- presumably the partition will not be touched again.  That means that you only have to back up one partition, the current partition.  And, next year, you'll only need to back up one partition.

A similar situation arises if you want to move data offline.  Dropping a partition containing the oldest year of data is pretty easy, compared to deleting the rows one-by-one.

When the number of partitions is only four, these considerations may not make much of a difference.  The key idea is that range partitioning assigns a each row to a known partition.  Hash partitioning assigns each row to a partition, but you don't know exactly which one.

EDIT:

The particular optimization that reduces the reading of partitions is called "partition pruning".  MySQL documents this pretty well [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-pruning.html).  In particular:

> For tables that are partitioned by HASH or KEY, partition pruning is
>   also possible in cases in which the WHERE clause uses a simple =
>   relation against a column used in the partitioning expression.

It would appear that partition pruning for inequalities (and even `in`) requires range partitioning.

Comment: Does the partition on YEAR improve performance of queries with where clause that refers to a range of DATES? or should i create partition based on DATE range?

Comment: @Murali . . . I believe that you need range partitioning to handle multiple dates or inequalities in the `where` clause.